# Why does declaring nested structures in C using typedef cause an error?

Tags: c, struct, nested, typedef

So in one of my C classes, the teacher was using struct and not typedef struct. When I tried, it showed an error.
This one does not show any error

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        char city[30];
        int hno;
        int pincode;
} address;

typedef struct {
        char name[30];
        int id;
        int salary;
        address a;
} employee;

int main(void) {
        employee e;
        scanf("%s %i %i %s %i %i", e.name, &e.id, &e.salary, e.a.city, &e.a.hno, &e.a.pincode);
        printf("%s %i %i %s %i %i\n", e.name, e.id, e.salary, e.a.city, e.a.hno, e.a.pincode);
        return 0;

}
```

Whereas this one does show an error. Why so?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        char name[30];
        int id;
        int salary;
        typedef struct {
                char city[30];
                int hno;
                int pincode;
        } address;
        address a;
} employee;

int main(void) {
        employee e;
        scanf("%s %i %i %s %i %i", e.name, &e.id, &e.salary, e.a.city, &e.a.hno, &e.a.pincode);
        printf("%s %i %i %s %i %i", e.name, e.id, e.salary, e.a.city, e.a.hno, e.a.pincode);
        return 1;

}
```

Doesn't my logic work that:

```c
typedef struct {
        // members of the structure
} name of the new variable;
```

declares a new data type named 'name of the new variable'?

Comment: You can't have nested typedefs.  Syntactically, typedef is a storage class and you can't put a storage class inside a structure definition.

Comment: Please quote the error message, verbatim, in full, as text and directly here. Especially if Jonathans comment did not satisfy you for any reason.

Comment: Just use the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946269/why-does-declaring-nested-structures-in-c-using-typedef-show-error#comment133953570_75946269), the succinct answer is:

> You can't have nested typedefs. Syntactically, `typedef` is a storage class, and you can't put a storage class inside a structure definition.

Justifying that claim takes a lot more effort.  I think it is best to refer to the C standard — [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) as a whole, and in particular [§6.7.1 Storage classes](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1) and [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1).

From §6.7.2.1, the syntax for a `struct-or-union-specifier` is:

> ```
>     struct-or-union-specifier:
>             struct-or-union identifier-opt { struct-declaration-list }
>             struct-or-union identifier
>     struct-or-union:
>             struct
>             union
>     struct-declaration-list:
>             struct-declaration
>             struct-declaration-list struct-declaration
>     struct-declaration:
>             specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-list-opt ;
>             static_assert-declaration
>     specifier-qualifier-list:
>             type-specifier specifier-qualifier-list-opt
>             type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-list-opt
>     struct-declarator-list:
>             struct-declarator
>             struct-declarator-list , struct-declarator
>     struct-declarator:
>             declarator
>             declarator-opt : constant-expression
> ```

Where I've transcribed something with `-opt` as a suffix, the standard has the word `opt` as a subscript.  It means that the element tagged is optional.

The key component of this rule is the `specifier-qualifier-list`, which can consist of one or more `type-specifier` items, and one or more `type-qualifier` items.  You need to look to other parts of §6.7 to find that §6.7.2 defines:

- `type-specifier` — the basic types like `int` and `char`, plus more specialized ones such as `struct-or-union-specifier`.

and §6.7.3 defines:

- `type-qualifier` — one of `const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, or `_Atomic`.

Note that `typedef` is not one of these items. (Beware: `typedef-name` appears in the list of `type-specifiers`, but that is an identifier, not the keyword `typedef`.)

From §6.7.1, the term `storage-class-specifier` is defined as:

> ```
> storage-class-specifier:
>             typedef
>             extern
>             static
>             _Thread_local
>             auto
>             register
> ```

Paragraph 5 says:

> 5 The typedef specifier is called a 'storage-class specifier' for syntactic convenience only; it is discussed in 6.7.8.

Hence my qualifier 'syntactically' in the comment.

From §6.7, the syntax of a declaration is:

> ```
> declaration:
>             declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list-opt ;
>             static_assert-declaration
> declaration-specifiers:
>             storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers-opt
>             type-specifier declaration-specifiers-opt
>             type-qualifier declaration-specifiers-opt
>             function-specifier declaration-specifiers-opt
>             alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers-opt
> init-declarator-list:
>             init-declarator
>             init-declarator-list , init-declarator
> init-declarator:
>             declarator
>             declarator = initializer
> ```

In a general `declaration`, you can have one `storage-class-specifier`.

> 2 At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration, except that `_Thread_local` may appear with static or extern.<sup>120)</sup>

The footnote references §6.11.5, which says:

> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

So, `typedef` (or `extern` or `static`, etc) should appear first in a declaration.

All of this demonstrates that the C grammar does not allow a `typedef` to appear in the middle of a structure declaration as you tried to do in your failing example.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you can use struct instead, like so

```
typedef struct {
        char name[30];
        int id;
        int salary;
        struct address {
                char city[30];
                int hno;
                int pincode;
        } add;
} employee;
```

Comment: You can get rid of `address` and just use an anonymous struct